# How to automatically vertically center text in Lyx?

Tags: tables, floats, formatting, lyx, tabularx

I have the following table in Lyx:

[image]

Here is how it looks in Lyx:
[image]

I want the text "My words" to be automatically vertically centered.
I also want the text for the items that are rotated to be vertically centered.

I tried right-clicking in a cell and going to More-->Settings and the settings look as follows, as you can see the vertical alignment is set to "Middle":

[image]

My temporary fix is to add the following:
use the `\vspace{}` command before the text "My words" and insert something like -3cm in the brackets.

For center aligning the rotated text I removed the text and inserted the following:

```
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ Item 1 }
```